# MySQL- IF Statement error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am having a problem with this SQL Statement:

```
$sql="SELECT b.FrameNumber, b.BikeCode, IF(b.ProductID = 0, p.FrameNumber) 
   AS FrameNumber 
 FROM BikeStock b LEFT JOIN Purchase p ON b.FrameNumber = p.FrameNumber 
 WHERE b.bikecode = '$bikecode'";
```

I want the SQL statement to work in this way:

```
Select FrameNumber & BikeCode from BikeStock 
THEN IF ProductID(BikeStock) is equal to 0 
     then it will grab the framenumber from the purchase table where bikecode is equal to $bikecode
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL `IF` statement has the following syntax: `IF(condition, expression if true, expression if false)`.

As far as I can see from your question you are actually looking for a `WHERE` clause (remember, you can have multiple conditions in `WHERE` – use boolean operators to combine them):

```
SELECT b.FrameNumber, b.BikeCode, p.FrameNumber
FROM BikeStock b
LEFT JOIN Purchase p ON b.FrameNumber = p.FrameNumber
WHERE b.bikecode = :bikecode AND b.ProductID = 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked however if it enters 0 is it possible to display a message saying "Out of Stock to the user"

Comment: You're probably best of replacing the value 0 with the error string in your frontend. (otherwise: `IF(p.FrameNumber = 0, 'Out of stock', p.FrameNumber) FrameNumber`

Answer (score 1):

You must add an else part to your [`if()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

```
SELECT b.FrameNumber, b.BikeCode,
       IF(b.ProductID = 0, p.FrameNumber, NULL) AS FrameNumber
FROM BikeStock b
LEFT JOIN Purchase p ON b.FrameNumber = p.FrameNumber
WHERE b.bikecode = '$bikecode'
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot an `else` part for that IF statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT b.FrameNumber, b.BikeCode, IF(b.ProductID = 0, p.FrameNumber, NULL /* ELSE HERE */) AS FrameNumber 
        FROM BikeStock b 
        LEFT JOIN Purchase p 
            ON b.FrameNumber = p.FrameNumber 
        WHERE b.bikecode = '$bikecode'";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $sql="SELECT b.FrameNumber, b.BikeCode, p.FrameNumber (
          CASE WHEN b.ProductID = 0 THEN p.FrameNumber ELSE NULL END AS Framenumber)  
          FROM BikeStock b 
          LEFT JOIN Purchase p ON b.FrameNumber = p.FrameNumber 
          WHERE b.bikecode = '$bikecode'";
```